# condition variable not holding wait across two threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, asyncore

Stumped on this thread sync I'm encountering.
Basically, I'm writing to a out buffer, and waiting on a condition variable until the read buffer is populated with a response from a socket. It's an incredibly simple thread sync.

```
def write_wait_response(self, buffer, timeout=30):
        '''
            Write and wait for response
            Params:
                Buffer BYTE encoded data
                Timeout timeout to wait for response
            Returns: 
                response str if successful
        '''
        self.buffer = buffer

        if self.waitLock(timeout):
            # condition var was signaled, we can return a response
            readbuf = bytes(self.readbuffer)
            self.readbuffer = b''
            return readbuf
        else:
            print("AsyncClientSocket: No response recieved from {} in {} seconds, dumping buffer".format(
                    self.sa, timeout))
            self.buffer = ''
            raise TimeoutError("AsyncClientSocket Timed Out")

def handle_read(self):
        self.readbuffer, address = self.recvfrom(2048)
        print(self.readbuffer)
        print("notifying")
        self.cond.notifyAll()
```

Seems straightforward enough, right? There's 1 thread waiting on the condition variable, and 1 thread (asyncore async callback loop) that will populate self.readbuffer and notify on the condition variable. Even more curious : if I do a time.sleep() instead of using a condition variable, I get a perfectly populated self.readbuffer on the calling thread of write_wait_response(). Obviously this is not a solution I can accept.

Here's what I'm expecting is happening:

1. Call to write_wait_response(buffer), this writes to buffer and waits
   on self.cond
2. asyncore callback loop calls handle_write, writes bytes to socket.
3. Server receives bytes, writes response.
4. asyncore callback loop sees bytes on the socket, reads into
   self.readbuffer, notifies cv
5. ?????????? write_wait_response should unblock?

Console output:

```
waiting <- thread 1 waiting on CV
AsyncClientSocket: writing 5 bytes <- thread 2: handle_write
b'200,2' <- thread 2: that's the server response
notifying <- thread 2: that's handle_read attempting to notify the held CV

error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <my_socket_stuff.AsyncClientSocket connected 127.0.0.1:50000 at 0x1051bf438> (<class 'RuntimeError'>:cannot notify on un-acquired lock
```

Note: at the end of this log, thread 1 is STILL waiting on self.cond. What's going on?

Full class:

```
class AsyncClientSocket(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, socketargs):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        family, type, proto, canonname, sa = socketargs
        self.sa = sa
        self.create_socket(family, type)

        if type == socket.SOCK_STREAM:
            self.connect( sa )
        elif type == socket.SOCK_DGRAM:
            pass

        self.buffer = b''
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.cond = threading.Condition(self.lock)
        self.readbuffer = b''

    def write_wait_response(self, buffer, timeout=30):
        '''
            Write and wait for response
            Params:
                Buffer BYTE encoded data
                Timeout timeout to wait for response
            Returns: 
                response str if successful
        '''
        self.buffer = buffer

        if self.waitLock(timeout):
            # condition var was signaled, we can return a response
            readbuf = bytes(self.readbuffer)
            self.readbuffer = b''
            return readbuf
        else:
            print("AsyncClientSocket: No response recieved from {} in {} seconds, dumping buffer".format(
                    self.sa, timeout))
            self.buffer = ''
            raise TimeoutError("AsyncClientSocket Timed Out")

    def waitLock(self, timeout):
        '''
            Wait for timeout seconds on CV
        '''
        try:
            self.cond.acquire()
            print("waiting")
            return self.cond.wait(timeout)
        finally:
            self.cond.release()


    def handle_connect(self):
        pass

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()

    def handle_read(self):
        self.readbuffer, address = self.recvfrom(2048)
        print(self.readbuffer)
        print("notifying")
        self.cond.notifyAll() 

    def writable(self):
        return (len(self.buffer) > 0)

    def handle_write(self):
        print("AsyncClientSocket: writing {} bytes".format(len(self.buffer)))
        self.readbuffer = b''
        sent = self.sendto(self.buffer, self.sa)
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]
```

Comment: Try a self-contained complete example, http://sscce.org/

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone well a concise example for this (didn't) exist. Now that I know that I was notifying the condition variable incorrectly, I can put together a SSCCE but prior to this I was under the impression the problem was tangled with asyncore somehow changing the thread context so the condition variable wasn't seen as held in the handle_read() function.

Comment: Many people have constructed many concise examples prior to understanding the problem.  It is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. This isn't related to asyncore. I was just signaling the condition variable incorrectly. [The python3 threading api doc says the calling thread of notify() must acquire the underlying lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition.notify) which makes sense, wouldn't want two producers to notify on the same condition variable. Would want one to block on the critical section while the other performs its task.

```
def handle_read(self):
    try:
        self.cond.acquire()
        self.readbuffer, address = self.recvfrom(2048)
        print(self.readbuffer)
        self.cond.notify() 
    finally:
        self.cond.release()
```